How to achieve this Form scrolling visual effect like iPhone's Settings
I want to achieve below visual presentation. A Form including sections like iPhone's Settings app, but with a rounded visual element on the top. And I want them to scroll together and have the same background color.

Code:
NavigationStack {
    HStack {
        Image("JoinUs") // Demo purpose
            .resizable()
            .frame(maxWidth: 360)
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    }
    .background(.green)
    .mask { RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25) }
    .padding()
    
    Form {
        Section {
            Text("Voice")
            Text("Speed")
            Text("Pitch")
            Text("Voice")
        } header: {
            Text("Sound")
        }
        
        Section {
            Text("Text Size")
        } header: {
            Text("System")
        }
        
        Section {
            Text("Voice")
            Text("Speed")
            Text("Pitch")
            Text("Voice")
        } header: {
            Text("Sound")
        }
        
        Section {
            Text("Voice")
            Text("Speed")
            Text("Pitch")
            Text("Voice")
        } header: {
            Text("Sound")
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("Settings")

Here is what I got:

Two problems I observed:

The white background of top HStack view. -> How to show the same background color, gray color in this case.
The top HStack view is not scrolled per form scrolling -> Try to put it into the Form, could scroll together but with smaller size and also white background problem.



1. Hide default Form background
Add this line:
.scrollContentBackground(.hidden)

2. Hide separation dividers
You can add this line on every Section:
.listRowSeparator(.hidden)

Or create your UnseparatedSection to easily reuse:
struct UnseparatedSection<Content: View, Header: View>: View {
    let content: Content
    let header: Header
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content,
         @ViewBuilder header: () -> Header) {
        self.content = content()
        self.header = header()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Section {
            content
        } header: {
            header
        }
        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
    }
}

3. Design NavigationLink:
struct CustomNavigationLink<Destination: View, Label: View>: View {
    let image: ImageResource
    let destination: Destination
    let label: Label
    
    init(image: ImageResource,
         @ViewBuilder destination: () -> Destination,
         @ViewBuilder label: () -> Label) {
        self.destination = destination()
        self.label = label()
        self.image = image
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationLink {
            destination
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Image(image)
                    .padding(.trailing, 8)
                label
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,
               maxHeight: .infinity,
               alignment: .leading)
        .padding(.vertical, 5)
        .padding(.horizontal, 15)
        .background{
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                .fill(.gray.opacity(0.2))
        }
    }
}

Your final code:
NavigationStack {
    Form {
        Image(.demo)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .frame(maxWidth: 360)
            .mask { RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25) }
        
        UnseparatedSection {
            CustomNavigationLink(image: .icon) {
                /*TODO: Add Destination View*/
            } label: {
                Text("Voice")
            }
            CustomNavigationLink(image: .icon) {
                /*TODO: Add Destination View*/
            } label: {
                Text("Speed")
            }
            CustomNavigationLink(image: .icon) {
                /*TODO: Add Destination View*/
            } label: {
                Text("Pitch")
            }
            CustomNavigationLink(image: .icon) {
                /*TODO: Add Destination View*/
            } label: {
                Text("Voice")
            }
        } header: {
            Text("Sound")
        }

        //...
    }
    .navigationTitle("Settings")
    .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
}


Nop, I need the default BG color of each form row, change as your code make them have the same color with outer BG. And as I mentioned in question, put top element (HStack) in form would make it smaller, how to solve it. Divider is fine for me, no need hide.

The example you provided look much different than the result you expected..

Well, I described the 2 problems I want to solve in question.

Solve it! Reference SO here. The magic is give the top view .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets()), this insect decreases the distance between inner content and its container (Form row in this case I think). Thus, the result is image fill the whole space of Form row.
Form {
    Section {
        HStack() {
            Image("JoinUs")
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
    } header: {
        Text("")
    }
    
    Section {
        Text("Voice")
        Text("Speed")
        Text("Pitch")
        Text("Voice")
    } header: {
        Text("Sound")
    }
}


